# Can create a remote server with MongoDB? How?

Tags: mongodb

My question, to be more clear, it is to create a server with mongodb on a cloud hosting (for example) and access it through another server.

Example:
I have a mobile app.
I hosted my mongoDB a cloud hosting (ubuntu).
I want to connect my app to the db on the server cloud.

**Is it possible? How?**

I'm joining this learning and my question was exactly MongoDB to create a server in a way that I could access it remotely.
Out of "localhost"? Different from all the tutorials I've seen.

Comment: if you can access the machine that is hosting the mongod, then you can access mongod server also by giving host options in mongo client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you are describing, I think you want to implement a 2-Tier-Architecture. For practically all use cases, **don't do it!**

It's definitely possible, yes. You can open up the MongoDB port in your firewall. Let's say your computer has a fixed IP or a fixed name like `mymongo.example.com`. You can then connect to `mongodb://mymongo.example.com:27017` (if you use the default port). But **beware**:

1. **Security** You need to make sure that clients can only perform those operations that you want to allow, e.g. using MongoDB integrated authentication, otherwise some random script kiddie will steal you database, delete it, or fill it with random data. Many servers, even if they don't host a well-known service, get attacked thousands of times per day. Also, you probably want to encrypt the connection so people can't spy on the connection. And to make it all worse, you will have to **store the database credentials in your client app**, which is **practically impossible** to do in a truly secure way.
2. **Software architecture** There is a ton of arguments against this architecture, but 1) alone should be enough. You never want to couple your client to the database, be it because of data migrations, software updates, security considerations, etc.

### 3-Tier

So what to do instead? Use a 3-Tier-Architecture: Host a server of some kind on `mymongo.example.com` that then connects to the database. That server could be implemented in nginx/node.js, iis/asp.net, apache/php,  or whatever. It could even be a plain old C application (like many game servers).

The mongodb can still reside on yet a different machine, but when you use a server, the database credentials are only known to the server, not to all the clients.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You would connect to MongoDB using the ip address of your host, or preferably using it's fully qualified hostname rather than "localhost". If you do that, you should secure your MongoDB installation otherwise anyone would be able to connect to your MongoDB instance. At an absolute minimum, enable MongoDB authentication. You should read up on [MongoDB Security](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-introduction/).

For a mobile application, you would probably have some sort of application server in front of MongoDB, e.g. your mobile application would not be connecting to MongoDB directly. In that case only your application server would be connecting to MongoDB, and you would secure MongoDB accordingly.