# How to display specific field(s) of a MongoDB on a web page

Tags: jquery, mongodb, http, web

I have a local MongoDb and I'm trying to display some of its fields on a web page separately. I can use this;

```
$(function() {
 $("#dataDiv").html('<object data="http://127.0.0.1:28017/mongoDB/data/"/>');
});
```

to display the entire db.

This db has fields as; "date", "url", "LineNo" ...etc.

Without making separate data sets, and querying them. How can I display these fields separately.

Is there a way to add some sort of "filters" at the end of `http://127.0.0.1:28017/mongoDB/data/` to query and display specific fields like date or url field?

Comment: Hm, directly accessing the database from the web client is usually a very bad idea (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23268138/257786). I'd suggest you look at two-tier vs. three-tier architectures and reconsider whether you really want to go down that path.

Comment: I understand your concern mnemosyn but this will be purely internal. There is no client or anything else. just for informational use only for my colleagues. But the problem is; like i said I can't find a way to query individual fields and displaying the whole DB at once is not ideal.